# Trying to pattern match partial file name in multiple folders using glob.glob

Tags: python-3.x, pattern-matching, glob

I am trying to find the newest version of files, each of which contains a unique reference code as part of their file name e.g. *12345*. I have a large list of reference codes which are in pairs because the program compares, the content of, two pdf files (each time through) using import fuzzywuzzy. The output is a list of fuzzy ratios and folder paths.

The problem I am having is using glob.glob to try and find the newest version of each file within a tree structure. I have it working fine when all the files are in a single folder.

The reference codes are in a list called listoflists. It loops through these and concatenates in the file path. I have tried using **\ which works (on the tree) when just simply checking a file suffix e.g. pdf. But when checking the tree for the reference codes using wildcards ether side of the code it is not  giving the results I expected

works:-

```
r"C:\compare2\*" + str(log1) + "*.pdf"
```

not working as expected:-

```
r"C:\compare2\**\*" + str(log1) + "*.pdf"
```

There is no error just when testing one folder I get the results expect then when using ** on more than one folder it's not checking all folders for the string.

```
keep_file_path1 = []
keep_file_path2 = []
fuzzy_list = []

def log_num(fuzzy_list, list_of_lists):
    # iterate through log numbers stored in list
    for log1, log2 in list_of_lists: 
        # passing a string into the file name by + concatenating +.
        file_path1 = r"C:\compare2\**\*" + str(log1) + "*.pdf"
        file_path2 = r"C:\compare2\**\*" + str(log2) + "*.pdf"
        # check if files exists
        if glob.glob(file_path1): 
            print("there is a match for log number: " + str(log1) + "  file_path1")
            if glob.glob(file_path2): 
                print("there is a match for log number: " + str(log2) + "  file_path2")
                # go to compare function
                compare(file_path1, file_path2)
        else:
            print ("NO Matches for log number: " + str(log1) + " or for log number: " + str(log2) + ".")
            continue # go find a different number
    else:  
        save_to_file(fuzzy_list, keep_file_path1, keep_file_path2)
```

Checking for newest version seem to work (when on one folder...) and is in another function

```
    # check for the newest file
    latest_file1 = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
```

I have not tried os.walk yet as want to try glob first. Can this be done with glob? Or would flattening the tree be the way to go considering I want the newest version of each.

Comment: So I got this working. It just needed the recursive=True tag adding.

Comment: details... It needed the `recursive=True` tag adding. Final code:-


```if glob.glob(file_path1, recursive=True):
            print("there is a match for log number: " + str(log1) + "  file_path1")
            if glob.glob(file_path2, recursive=True): 
                print("there is a match for log number: " + str(log2) + "  file_path2")```


It is worth knowing that glob is matching the 'path' not the 'filename' like fnmatch. Glob is very powerful and lets you traverse a large file structure using **\  e.g.

`file_path1 = r"C:\compare2\**\**\**\*" + str(log1) + "*.pdf"`